# Need a sanity check on my SQLite query?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, variables, join

Simple iPhone app that shows user a list of coupons based on the category of coupon they select.

I haven't tested this yet because I'm still a long way from even having the interface built - I just wanted to sanity check my approach here before I end up chasing some crazy error for days.

```
- (BBSelectedCoupons *)BBSelectedCoupons:(char)SelectedCategory {
   BBCouponDetails *retval = nil;
   NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, MerchantName, ShortDeal 
   FROM coupons JOIN SelectedCategory ON coupons.CouponID=SelectedCategory.CouponID 
   ORDER BY id ASC WHERE SelectedCategory=%d", SelectedCategory];
```

My questions are as follows:

1) On line 1, am I allowed to use (char) as I have?  Examples I've seen only use (int).

2) On lines 4 and 5, I use the term "SelectedCategory" twice - once to refer to the table right after JOIN, and the second to refer to the second table that's part of the test.  Then, after WHERE, I only have "SelectedCategory" defined once - is that going to work?  I'm planning on defining "SelectedCategory" based on the button the user clicks.

3) On line 5, is "%d" going to play nice with a "string" variable?  Or should it be something like "$d" or "@d"?

Thanks to anyone who could take a look and give me a "looks good" or a "you suck".

If I suck, a link to something I could read would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure, why not?
2. You can disambiguate using short name. Using a shorter example: `select * from table t where t.col1 = 5;`
3. `%d` really refers to an integer so you may get odd results. I'm not going to look up the correct format for a char because I don't think this is a good approach. You should really be using bind parameters. To do this you define the query with a question mark where you currently have `%d`. Then before you execute your query, you `sqlite3_bind_int` to "populate" the field. This avoids SQL injection exploits when using string fields and has some performance advantages (since you can do all your preparing in advance).